# Использование задержки внутри цикла

Tags: javascript

Есть такой цикл, есть цель чтобы elevatorLevel увеличивался только раз в секунду, ниже пытался сделать через setTimeout, не выходит

```
while (nextLevel > elevatorLevel) {
   elevatorLevel++;
}



while (nextLevel > elevatorLevel) {
  setTimeout(() => {
     elevatorLevel++;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Возможно ли в цикле вообще сделать задержку, а если нет то как без цикла возможно подобное реализовать?

Comment: Можно сделать не цикл, а рекурсию. Пусть из callback'а функции `setTimeout` вызывается следующий `setTimeout`, если условие верно.

```JavaScript

function step() {
 setTimeout(() => {
   elevatorLevel++;
   if (nextLevel > elevatorLevel) step();   
 }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: @SergeyK, а `nextLevel > elevatorLevel` будет возвращать `false` таймер будет молоть впустую?

Comment: @De.Minov, Если условие будет ложным, то цепочка рекурсии прервётся и следующий таймер не будет создан.

Comment: @SergeyK. ах да, прошу прощения, не так увидел код. Вот по этому лучше отвечать не в комментах, а в ответе

Comment: @De.Minov, Разумеется лучше, но вопрос был закрыт и ответить нельзя, но помочь хотелось.